# Grails UTF-8 classes, compiler complaining for wrong file name

Tags: grails, utf-8, groovy

I have a grails code generator that generates files in UTF-8 encoding. I need the UTF-8, as my classes contain Unicode strings.

When trying to compile the code compiler complains on:

---

```
One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement,
the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. 
Solutions are to change the file name or to change the class name.
```

---

When encoding code to ASCII, all works perfect. It seems that compiler read class name and file name differently when I use UTF-8.

Any workaround?

Comment: Can you post a small example that fails to compile?

Comment: here is an example:

D:\Develop\Tiv\grails-app\domain\tiv\Contacts.groovy contains at least two definitions of the class Contacts.
One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. Solutions are to change the file name or to change the class name.
 @ line 2, column 1.
   class Contacts {
   ^

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem...
I used UTF-8 with BOM. once removed BOM, all worked fine.